# Overflow ActionBar entry missing for ICS Phone using Compat Lib

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Using compat lib r6. Testing on Galaxy Nexus (ICS).

Have: `android:minSdkVersion="13" android:targetSdkVersion="14"` in manifest

Menu items defined as:

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
    android:title="@string/refresh_menu"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

In portrait the action bar has the search control but NO overflow action bar menu item.

In landscape the action bar has both the search control and the overflow action bar menu item (I don't get the icon which is disappointing as there is plenty of room for it).

On a Honeycomb/ICS tablet everything works perfectly, get my search control and an icon entry.

Am a doing something wrong or is this looking like a bug in the compat lib? Thanks in advance. Peter.

**Edit 1 - Further Info and potential solution**
What I forget to add is that in `onCreateOptionsMenu` I de-iconify the search control. If I don't de-iconify I get the 'refresh' menu. So this is now sort of making sense although I would still expect to see the overflow action entry given that I cannot collapse the search control (as there is no close button) from the UI.

**Edit 2**
OK I can get this working if I force the refresh item to always be on the action bar and re-order:

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
    android:title="@string/refresh_menu"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the overflow menu there's only text so you have to add the appropriate flag:

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
```

Comment: Thanks @ramdroid, but doesn't make a difference as the overflow menu is there for landscape. As mentioned in my edit I think that the problem is with the de-iconified search view which doesn't have a close button.